# Update express session after request has been made?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

If I have two requests at the same time, and change some values in the session for one of them, if I get req.session it still has the old values. They don't update until a new request is started. Is there a way to update the req.session value to reflect the most recent value?

Comment: What session store are you using with express-session?

Comment: Can you describe what it is in your session that you're updating that you want the 2nd request in flight to see the moment it is changed by the first request?  I'm wondering if you have a race condition in your design and perhaps you should be using a different design that uses different tools (such as database tools for managing concurrency issues).

Comment: I'm using connect-mongo to store the sessions. This is to prevent people from commenting too quickly, when it gets the request it sets session.nextComment to 30 seconds in the future. But if 2 requests are made at the same time, both requests start before nextComment is updated for either of them, so they both end up going through. Was hoping I could somehow update the value before checking it so only one would.

Comment: For true concurrency control, you will need to use something that is not subject to race conditions. That won't be anything in your session because data is read from the mongo db into a session object and is then subject to race conditions if tested or modified there because some other request may have a different copy of the same data. If one is modified slightly before the other, the other doesn't know that. The usual tool to use for something like this is some sort of atomic operation that checks and sets (in one atomic operation) whatever it is you're keeping track of, often a db function.